# Is there a test to see if an Object is an associative Array?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Is there a test to see if an Object is an associative array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an Object as an associative array, you are simply adding dynamic properties to it, with arbitrary values.

for...in loops iterate over *only dynamic properties* of an Object, so if you create a for...in loop and it completes one loop, you will know that the Object is an associative array.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/statements.html#for..in

```
function isObjectAssociativeArray(obj:Object):Boolean
{
    for (var prop in obj)
    {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "dynamic" property only exists on Class, to my knowledge.

Comment: we're talking about 2 different things.  the 'dynamic' descriptor in a class definition means it can be assigned 'dynamic properties' at runtime.  All generic Objects are by default 'dynamic' and can thus be assigned 'dynamic properties'.  

ex: var o:Object = {prop1:"value1", prop2:"value2"};   

 will create a object with 2 dyamic properties o.prop1 and o.prop2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [getQualifiedClassName](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName()) and see if the return type is "Object". I haven't tested this myself, but it accepts flash primitives (Object, Array, String...) as well as Classes.